# How Migrate ASP.Net Identity 2.1 to IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-identity-2

A few years ago we had created an OAuth identity server using ASP.Net Identity 2.1 using OWin middleware. We'd like to switch over to using OAuth 2.0 with IdentityServer4 as our new middleware. During the transition we'll have both old ASP.Net Identity 2 apps working while we build new IdentityServer4 based apps. Is there a way to reuse the password store from ASP.Net Identity 2.1 so that we can have both systems in use at the same time during the transition process?